When should ATC terminate radar service to VFR aircraft?
According to FAA order 7110.65AA 7-6-11,
"Basic radar services should be provided to the extent possible, workload permitting. Terminate radar service to aircraft landing at airports other than those where sequencing service is provided at a sufficient distance from the airport to permit the pilot to change to the appropriate frequency for traffic and airport information."
If sequencing service is provided at a sufficient distance from the airport, when should ATC terminate radar service? I wonder why there is an exception in paragragh 7-6-11.

The intention of that paragraph is to give the pilot enough time to safely communicate their intentions and perform the necessary coordination at the landing airport. This may be a Class D airport where Tower provides the sequencing services, or it may be a non-towered airport where the pilots sequence themselves on CTAF.
For a towered airport the "Transfer of Communications Point" will be specified in the Letter of Agreement between the Tower and Approach facilities. Six or seven miles from the airport is a common minimum.
For a non-towered airport there will be no formal Letter of Agreement so it comes down to technique on the part of the controller. I consider it very poor service to hold on to a pilot inside of five miles from the field; unless I get distracted by something else I will generally terminate services and let them change to CTAF at around ten miles.
Of course the pilot may request a frequency change at any time.

If sequencing service is provided (by Approach) then the Transfer of Communications Point is the required point at which communications should be transferred. This may or may not be a "termination of radar services." Some Tower facilities have the requisite equipment and training to provide radar services themselves; at other towered airports the Approach controller will specifically say "radar services terminated, contact Tower." See 5–1–9b3.
